# What is the difference between Oracle clusterware and Real Application Clusters?

Tags: oracle, clustering

What is the difference between Oracle clusterware and Real Application Clusters? If we have 2 servers and want to join them into a cluster why there are two separate software products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle Clusterware](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/clusterware/overview/index.html) is the clustering software that is a component of an Oracle RAC setup. Rather than being seen as a separate software product, Clusterware is part of the software stack (which includes the OS, ASM, Oracle RDBMS) that makes up an Oracle RAC cluster/deployment. Oracle support other clustering products in a RAC environment on some operating systems.

Comment: You could (in theory at least) also use the clusterware tools independently from RAC, to "cluster" apps other than Oracle RDBMS. I don't think that's widely used though.